# How to fix two row headers in a table when scrolled down?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have fiddle here : https://jsfiddle.net/oed1k6m7/ . Which has two `td` inside `thead`.And

```
thead th {
  position: -webkit-sticky; /* for Safari */
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}
```

this one only made first row fixed.How can I do that for both `td`'s in thead?
[image]

As you can see above,only one row is fixed the other one is still there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because both has `top:0` and they overlap. You should set a different `top` value for the second line.

```css
div {
  max-height: 10em;
  overflow: scroll;
}

thead th {
  position: -webkit-sticky; /* for Safari */
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

thead tr:nth-child(2) th {
  top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>head</th>
        <th>head</th>
        <th>head</th>
        <th>head</th>
        <th>head</th>
        <th>head</th>
        <th>head</th>
        <th>head</th>
        <th>head</th>
        <th>head</th>
        <th>head</th>
        <th>head</th>
        <th>head</th>
        <th>head</th>
        <th>head</th>
        <th>head</th>
        <th>head</th>
        <th>head</th>
        <th>head</th>
        <th>head</th>
        <th>head</th>
        <th>head</th>
        <th>head</th>
        <th>head</th>
        <th>head</th>
        <th>head</th>
        <th>head</th>
        <th>head</th>
        <th>head</th>
        <th>head</th>
        <th>head</th>
        <th>head</th>
        <th>head</th>
        <th>head</th>
        <th>head</th>
        <th>head</th>
        <th>head</th>
        <th>head</th>
        <th>head</th>
        <th>head</th>
        <th>head</th>
        <th>head</th>
        <th>head</th>
        <th>head</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>head</th>
        <th>head</th>
        <th>head</th>
        <th>head</th>
        <th>head</th>
        <th>head</th>
        <th>head</th>
        <th>head</th>
        <th>head</th>
        <th>head</th>
        <th>head</th>
        <th>head</th>
        <th>head</th>
        <th>head</th>
        <th>head</th>
        <th>head</th>
        <th>head</th>
        <th>head</th>
        <th>head</th>
        <th>head</th>
        <th>head</th>
        <th>head</th>
        <th>head</th>
        <th>head</th>
        <th>head</th>
        <th>head</th>
        <th>head</th>
        <th>head</th>
        <th>head</th>
        <th>head</th>
        <th>head</th>
        <th>head</th>
        <th>head</th>
        <th>head</th>
        <th>head</th>
        <th>head</th>
        <th>head</th>
        <th>head</th>
        <th>head</th>
        <th>head</th>
        <th>head</th>
        <th>head</th>
        <th>head</th>
        <th>head</th>
      </tr>

    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
      </tr>
           <tr>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
      </tr>
           <tr>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
      </tr>
           <tr>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
      </tr>
           <tr>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the two `th` are stuck when they reach the top of their parent. The first one is already on top and when the second one reach the top, it sticks under the first `th`.

What are your trying to achieve exactly?